# How does one systematically traverse OCaml representations of Coq ASTs terms?

Tags: coq, abstract-syntax-tree, ocaml, coq-serapi

I want to be able to (tree) traverse Coq terms (e.g. in OCaml or using their s-expression representation in any language).

My main challenge is to figure out how to do this systematically because I noticed two things that make arbitrary tree traversal difficult (or at least none obvious to me):

1. There might be arbitrary OCaml records with any size in the OCaml data type. Thus, I don't know what the "key" names or the length of the record (represented as a list in the s-exp) would be.
2. There are types that could be **any** type -- due to type variables `'a`. Therefore making pattern matching challenging in a programmatically (since I don't know what constructors might appear before hand).

Thus, I am unsure how to traverse "Coq ASTs" programmatically in a systematic way in code that I write (say in OCaml, Coq or even Python).

**So: How do I programmatically traverse Coq AST terms from their ocaml representation?**

---

## More details

For example, let me give you a concrete example when interacting with coq-serapi:

Run the proof script first (why not):

```
(Add () "
Theorem add_easy_0: forall n:nat, 0 + n = n. simpl. reflexivity. Show Proof.")
(Exec 5)
```

then send the proof term back (a lambda term) to coq-serapi to parse into a "nice" AST for us (argh had to wrap it in a definition of coq returns a syntax error):

```
(Parse () "Definition id := (fun n : nat => eq_refl).")
```

then one gets the coq-ast (from the OCaml code I believe):

```
(Answer 2 Ack)
(Answer 2
 (ObjList
  ((CoqAst
    ((v
      ((control ()) (attrs ())
       (expr
        (VernacDefinition (NoDischarge Definition)
         (((v (Name (Id id)))
           (loc
            (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0) (line_nb_last 1)
              (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 11) (ep 13)))))
          ())
         (DefineBody () ()
          ((v
            (CLambdaN
             ((CLocalAssum
               (((v (Name (Id n)))
                 (loc
                  (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                    (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 22) (ep 23))))))
               (Default Explicit)
               ((v
                 (CRef
                  ((v (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ()) (Id nat)))
                   (loc
                    (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                      (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 26) (ep 29)))))
                  ()))
                (loc
                 (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                   (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 26) (ep 29)))))))
             ((v
               (CRef
                ((v (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ()) (Id eq_refl)))
                 (loc
                  (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                    (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 33) (ep 40)))))
                ()))
              (loc
               (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                 (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 33) (ep 40)))))))
           (loc
            (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0) (line_nb_last 1)
              (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 18) (ep 40)))))
          ())))))
     (loc
      (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0) (line_nb_last 1)
        (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 0) (ep 42)))))))))
(Answer 2 Completed)
```

but if you inspect the s-expression more carefully there are potential issues. For example, reading the coq-serapi documentation we know we are getting a `coq_object` in the reply:

```
| CoqAst of Vernacexpr.vernac_control   (*
Coq Abstract Syntax tress, as produced by the parser
```

and thus the first thing is likely a `vernac_control` (or a `CAst.t` [honestly I'm not sure what the `and vernac_control = vernac_control_r CAst.t` ocaml syntax means](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.13/api/coq/Vernacexpr/index.html). But there are only two options so it's easy to systematize). The main issue is if we get the type `CAst.t`. Look at it's def:

```
type 'a t = private {
v : 'a;
loc : Loc.t option;
}
```

so basically `v` can be **any type** due to the type variable `'a`. Which seems like a nightmare since how do I write a pattern match? Or a python if statement to detect what even the constructor options might be? I think this is the most serious issue if I want to even attempt to write a traversal for this. My fear is definitively confirmed since if you look at the s-expression I copy pasted we received plenty of `v` names in it...which makes we wonder how do I even traverse the coq-ast.

The other issue (which seems a bit more minor) is that we might get a record. Which is shown as a list in an s-expression...and I suppose we could infer what type of ocaml coq record it is from the lenght and the names of the "indices" but if I receive one that I didn't expect my code will crash.

So how does one traverse a s-expression/ocaml ast systematically?

---

## Appendix 1:

I think this question is extremely related to this other one: [What are Generic Arguments in Coq and how are they structured in their OCaml code?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/what-are-generic-arguments-in-coq-and-how-are-they-structured-in-their-ocaml-cod) . I think so because this one is about coq term traversal but the other one points out the (apparent?) inconsistencies coq-serapi might give. Thus, there can't be a systematic coq traversal if the terms given to the user from the OCaml code is incosnsistent.

Comment: OCaml (and the other MLs) have had the *glorious* idea of placing type arguments to parametrized types *before* the type constructor. What is `list int` in Coq is `int list` in OCaml. `vernac_control = vernac_control_r CAst.t` means a `vernac_control` is a `CAst.t` (which gives location info) where `'a` is `vernac_control_r`... OCaml is a statically typed language... if you just trace the type definitions there should never be confusion about what goes where.

Comment: @HTNW fantastic answer! thank you. Not I realized that when I saw `and vernac_control = vernac_control_r CAst.t` in the mutual recursion definition, that I didn't know what that meant but now I see what it means. Thanks again!

Comment: @HTNW curious, when we define `'a list` in ocaml but I create an object `Cons(1. [])` -- `'a` is known at run time, right? I feel there must be something wrong because OCaml is compiled but the current example you provided (and I provided) only seems to get around it because the new type defined defined it explicitly defined by the user e.g. as if we did `type my_int_list = int list`. This is the reason in the Coq AST it might work...but does this work in general? What about the runtime example I provided?

Comment: I think this question is extremely related to this other one: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/what-are-generic-arguments-in-coq-and-how-are-they-structured-in-their-ocaml-cod . I think so because this one is about coq term traversal but the other one points out the (apparent?) inconsistencies coq-serapi might give. Thus, there can't be a systematic coq traversal if the terms given to the user from the OCaml code is incosnsistent.